# Are there always 2 solutions to the square root of a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

If you have an equation such as $x^2=9$, $x$ will have 2 solutions. But then if you have the equation $x=\sqrt9$, then $x$ cannot be plus minus $3$.

However, does this still follow through with complex numbers?
For example, if I was given that

1. $(x+iy)^2=1-i\quad$
   as well as
2. $x+iy=\sqrt{1-i},$

Would only the first equation have 2 possible values for $x$ and $y$, or would both 1. and 2. have 2 possible solutions?

Comment: We don't usually write $\sqrt z$ for $z\in\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R$; there are two solutions to $w^2=z$, unless  $z=0$

Comment: For any nonzero complex $z$ there are two complex numbers $w$ satisfying $w^2 = z$.  One could deduce this from the fact that $(-1)^2 = 1$: if $w^2 = z$, then $(-w)^2 = (-1)^2(w^2) = w^2 = z$ also, and $-w$ is different from $w$ whenever $w$ is nonzero.  To say that one of the numbers $w$ with $w^2 = z$ is "the" square root of $z$ is to make a choice.  Even in the real case (where the choice is "take the nonnegative one") this presents some difficulties. It is subtler in the complex case because the choice of taking "the nonnegative one" is not available.

Comment: Also in the complex numbers , we have $(-w)^2=w^2$ , hence if $w$ saitisfies $w^2=z$ , then $-w$ does as well. $w=-w$ implies $2w=0$ and therefore $w=0$. The fundamental theorem of algebra guarantees the existence of a solution. Hence for $z\ne 0$, there are exactly two solutions of $w^2=z$. And for $z=0$, of course, the only solution is $w=0$.